# How to make a curved/wavy footer line with a google map in the back of it?

Tags: html, css, dictionary

How could I make a wavy, curved, footer like below?

[image]

I tried with css `before::` and `after::`, I tried with `border-right-bottom-radius`, and many tricks like that.

I have this picture element:

[image]

Could I use that?

I want the Google map which is below to be with `z-index: -1`. What I mean is that I would like the Google map to appear in the back of the above curved line(`position: absolute`).

Can somebody help me to execute that footer with Google map and top curved green border in code ?

Comment: Png transparent background-image for upper div and negative margin for div with google map, and z-index may solve the problem but not with that pattern background

Comment: Does the map have to be dynamic (= a real Google Map `iframe`), or is it just a static `img` you can edit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a client a little ways back, probably a year ago, who wanted the same thing, but without using an image. And here is the code I used. See http://jsfiddle.net/yrovnjg3/ for the action. This creates 2 "claws" (one being upside down) that looks almost like your image above. I put in some CSS at the end of the demo to help separate and show the 2 different claws, like the pink box. Just delete those last few lines and everything will look like the image above, except the color will be red and won't at an angle. Just follow the instructions below. Have fun. Hope this helps.

```
<!--image-->
<div id="line"></div>
<!--google map-->
/*
If you change "#line {transform: rotate(0deg);}", then you'll need to adjust: "#line:after {top: ---; left: ---;}". Usually just changing one or both down or up a number will fix rotation stacing problems.
To some degree, changing "border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 0px;" to something like "border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 0px;" will act like "transform: rotate();".
Do NOT change "#line:after {transform: rotate(180deg);}". Doing so will mess everything up.

If any of the lines marked with an "x" are changed, you'll need to change all, or most, of the ones marked with an "x"
*/

#line {position: relative; /*can be "relative" or "absolute". doesn't really matter.*/
       width: 0px;
       height: 0px;
       /*x*/ transform: rotate(0deg);}

#line:after, #line:before {position: absolute;
                           content: "";
                           /*x*/ width: 50px; /*if this is changed, then don't forget to change "left" in ":after".*/
                           /*x*/ height: 50px; /*x*/
                           /*x*/ border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 0px; /*only have a value on the first set.*/
                           /*x*/ border-top: 12px solid #ff0000; /*can be any color you want.*/}

#line:before {/*just if you want to customize the first half of the shape.*/}

#line:after {/*x*/ top: -50px;
             /*x*/ left: 50px;
             transform: rotate(180deg); /*don't even think about changing this.*/}



/*REMOVE THESE. DEMO PURPOSES ONLY:*/
body{margin:100px;}
#line{background:pink;width:20px;height:20px;}
#line:before{border-color:blue;}
#line:after{border-color:green;}
```